# How to populate html texbox with mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to populate the textboxes of a CRUD with the information obtained from a query. I use a stored procedure which already works.
I mainly want to give an ID, click search and populate the rest of the texboxes with the clients rest of information. The rest of the buttons already work so I think my problem is located in this section of code:

```
if(isset($_POST['btnBuscar']))
{
  $opc = "buscar";
  $idcliente = ($_POST['txtIdCliente']);
  $nombre = ($_POST['txtNombre']);
  $apaterno = ($_POST['txtApPat']);
  $amaterno = ($_POST['txtApMat']);
  $tel = ($_POST['txtTel']);
  $email = ($_POST['txtEmail']);
  $fecalta = ($_POST['txtFechaAlta']);

  $query = "CALL sp_clientes('$opc',$idcliente,'$nombre','$apaterno','$amaterno',$tel,'$email','$fecalta')";
  
if(mysqli_query($con,$query)){
    header("location:Clientes.php?searched=1");
```

this next part where I have doubts

```
($_POST['txtIdCliente']) = $reg['IdCliente'];
    ($_POST['txtNombre'])= $reg['Nombre'];
    ($_POST['txtApPat']) = $reg['APaterno'];
    ($_POST['txtApMat']) = $reg['ApMaterno'];
    ($_POST['txtTel']) = $reg['Telefono'];
    ($_POST['txtEmail']) = $reg['Email'];
    ($_POST['txtFechaAlta']) = $reg['FecAlta'];
  }
```

Comment: Why? For editing?

Comment: Yes, it could be for later editing. I intend to use this instead of a data grid view, when the button search is pressed I want all the information to be filled on the html controls or textbox

Comment: So, first, you'd need a form.

Comment: Yes, I already have a form, and those are the names of the textboxes, I already know that the register, delete and modify buttons work, but I just need advise on the syntax of how to load the information into the textboxes

Comment: You need to explain clearly in your question what you are trying to do and what part isn't working. All you have said us "*This last part is where the problem is*"... but you haven't told us *what* the problem is. We can't help if we don't know what we are trying to help with!

Comment: Sorry, made an edit. I hope to be more clear now

Comment: you want the data from db into textbox ?

Comment: That is correct, Aroon

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example. you can achieve more by appending HTML in PHP

```
echo '<input type="text" style="background-color:blue" id="'.$_POST['txtNombre'].'" name="content'.$_POST['txtNombre'].'" value="'.$_POST['txtNombre'].'"></input>';
```